# how to pass parameter from @Test method in 1 class file to a annotated method in another class file(testNG)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, apache-poi, testng

I am using selenium webdriver with java + testng to test my application gui. i have 2 class files in my project (same package). 1 class file has all the @Test methods and the second class file has 1 method which is used to generate an excel file with Id's generated in the test method in the first class file. Basically my AUT generates a unique ID each time i run the test method, which i need to capture.

code looks like this -
Test Method in 1st class file

```
@Test (invocationCount = 1)
  public void TestIncident() {


      ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
      FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("selenium");

      WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
      vDriver = driver;
      driver.manage().window().maximize();

      driver.get("URL");
      driver.findElement(By.id("username-id")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.id("username-id")).sendKeys("username");
      driver.findElement(By.id("pwd-id")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.id("pwd-id")).sendKeys("password");
      driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();

      Thread.sleep(5000);


      driver.findElement(By.id("reg_img_304316340")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='PageBody pbChrome']"));
      //new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='PageBody pbChrome']"))).perform();


      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'Page1')]")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(.,'New Page')]")).click();
      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='PageBody pbChrome']")).click();


      uniqueID  = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='WIN_0_304248710']/descendant::dd[@class='HNavSelected arfid304247442 ardbnz3Btn_BCItem3']/descendant::a[@class='btn']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");

      driver.findElement(By.id("arid_WIN_3_303530000")).clear();
      driver.findElement(By.id("arid_WIN_3_303530000")).click();

}
```

In the 2nd class file in the same package, i am doing something like this -

```
@BeforeClass
    public void createExcel() throws IOException
{

        System.out.println("did this run");
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("IncidentNo");
        //some code to save uniqueID in excel file
}
```

Now i cannot figure out a way to send `uniqueID` from the `@Test` method in the first class file to the method in the second class file which saves these uniqueID's to an excel sheet. any suggestions whats an effective way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call a method of the 2nd Class from your test class, passing the uniqueID as an argument.

Your code should look like this

```
    ExcelUtils objExcelutils; //Object of your 2nd class

    public class Test{


    //all the code from your first class


      objExcelutils.writeUniqueID(uniqueID);

    }

    // this is your 2nd class
    int rowCount=1;   //variable for the row count
    public class Excelutils
    {

    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.createSheet("IncidentNo");
       public void writeUniqueID(String uniqueID)
       {
           HSSFRow row = worksheet.createRow(rowCount);
           HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(rowCount);
           cell.setCellValue(uniqueID);
           rowCount++;
       }

    }
    try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("JavaBooks.xlsx"))        {
            workbook.write(outputStream);
        }

}
```